# How to run a CGI script in another process through Apache

Tags: java, apache, memory, process, cgi

I have a CGI script that executes a very intensive Java application:

start.cgi
`#!/bin/sh

cd /var/server/; screen -d -m java -Xmx800M -Xms800M -jar jarfile.jar > /dev/null 2>&1 &

echo "Server command executed.";`

This executes just fine by navigating to it in an internet browser and through an SSH session.

But when run by navigating to it with an internet browser, it seems to run under the apache process...
Output of `top`:
  `PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND

  7651 apache    24   0 1149m  38m 9012 S  0.0  2.5   0:01.42 java`

When run via an SSH session `top` outputs:
`PID USER PR NI VIRT RES SHR S %CPU %MEM TIME+ COMMAND

 7685 root      23   0 1163m 205m 9432 S 12.3 13.6   0:06.03 java`

I believe the CGI script is running under the apache process...
Can someone please point out what I have done wrong or point me in the right direction?

Thanks!
 Justin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to chmod your script file to set the uid as root - but I'd have to say that that is not a great idea. Is there a problem in the job running as apache rather than root? Surely the only reason that it runs as root from an ssh session is because you have logged in as root?

Comment: Yes, I am logged in as root in the SSH session, but somehow apache isn't giving the Java applications enough RAM or CPU allowance, The script seems to barely work, it just won't get passed the authentication process...

Comment: OK - if the processes is asynchronous, you could consider "nohup" ing it and running it the background. It'd start a new Unix process, but I'm not sure it'd be easy to wait for it to finish. It'd be something along the lines on nohup start.cgi &

Comment: It still has the same behavior... In `top` the 'RES' is only 38m comparing it it the SSH session, that's low. It is 205m in the SSH session, how is that possible?

Comment: Do you have RLimitMEM set in your httpd.conf? ( That aside, I'm out of ideas I'm afraid )